# how to put values into one row in sql

Tags: sql-server-2005

I make query to get customer information:

For example i would like to know from what catalogue client made orders and after query i get:

```
client1 ABC
client1 BCD
client1 DDD
```

So i would like to put all those catalogues into 1 row:

```
client1 ABC, BCD, DDD

SELECT clientid, catalogue FROM A 
INNER JOIN B ON A.A=B.A
WHERE orderdate > '20110101'
```

Is it possible to make it so?

What should i use for it?

Thank you!

Comment: http://www.projectdmx.com/tsql/rowconcatenate.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simulating group_concat MySQL function in MS SQL Server 2005?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TRY THIS**

```
State (Tablename)  
City (Columnname)  
Chennai   
Madurai   
Coimbatore   

    declare @retstr varchar(8000)   
     select Top 5 @retstr = 
     COALESCE(@retstr + ';','') + City   
     from State   print @retstr   Result:

Chennai;Madurai;Coimbatore
```

[MORE ON BELOW LINK](http://sqlservercodebook.blogspot.com/2008/04/covert-row-to-column-in-sql-server-2005.html)